# Domain accounts not visible in ACL on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, file-server

We have two new servers running Windows Server 2008. One is a file server and one a DC. The file server is joined to the domain, but when we attempt to edit NTFS ACLs, domain objects are not available. Any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not available"?  What are you seeing, and what are you expecting to see?  Is the domain available and set as your search location when attempting to add objects?

Comment: Are you signing in with a domain account?

Answer (score 0):

In the Select Users and Groups dialog box are you making sure that the Locations field is the domain and not the server? See below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, domain is available. I am signing in with a domain account. This is what I am doing: right click on folder, choose properties. Click on the Security tab. Click the Edit button to change permissions. Click Add to add an entry to the ACL. The dialog box appears to select Users or Groups. The object types selected include Users, Groups, or Built-in Security Principals. From this location: reads SERVERNAME. If I click on the Locations button, there is only one location available: SERVERNAME. The domain does not appear as an available location.

Comment: The domain controller was missing a forward looking zone in DNS. Problem solved.